# A typical bank database for credit card accounts?

Tags: data-request, finance, bank

I am working on a project to develop a system that detect credit card fraud. I have no data set to test my system on instead I want to create a database that looks similar to that of a real bank database.

Are there some samples out there? I mean one that would show some columns to include? Of course, I know it depends on the requirements of my system but, what have you done - that is what I want to see.

I know some would have worked on similar situations. What have you included?

**PS:** I know (from SO) that credit card information must not be stored without authorization or some policies out there **BUT this is specifically for demonstrating my system, just demonstration**!

Answer (score 1):

Datasets like this will typically be "academic", meaning scrubbed and anonymized and used for demo or publishing purposes.

One example is the "[German Credit fraud data](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/file/n23121/credit_fruad.arff)", which is in [ARFF format](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) as used by [Weka machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29).

> This dataset classifies people described by a set of attributes as good or bad credit risks. Comes in two formats (one all numeric). Also comes with a cost matrix.

- [UCI Machine Learning Repo](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+%28German+Credit+Data%29)
- [Data folder](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/)
- [Converting ARFF to CSV](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/).

As far as I can tell, this data is the story of 1000 credit lines and not specifically credit cards.

One useful thing may be to reverse search who is using this dataset, namely [who links to it](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=links:http:%2F%2Fweka.8497.n7.nabble.com%2Ffile%2Fn23121%2Fcredit_fruad.arff).

([my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152354/2327328))

---

Other possibilities:

- [Australian Credit Card Approval](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+%28Australian+Credit+Approval%29) dataset (or [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Credit+Approval))

> This file concerns credit card applications. All attribute names and values have been changed to meaningless symbols to protect confidentiality of the data.
>
> This dataset is interesting because there is a good mix of attributes -- continuous, nominal with small numbers of values, and nominal with larger numbers of values. There are also a few missing values.

Comment: Well, thanks for edit and response, this has provided me with a start. I am looking into it.